# How to move next (navigate button)from one string content to another string in edittext in android

Tags: android

I have multiple strings in my java file.

I want to create a Next button that navigate through string content on button click one by one in a single `EditText`.

How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean under "button to navigate through string content"? Words to be highlighted one after another or what?

Comment: Please post your java file code and XML layout file.

Comment: String apple= "This is an applie";

Comment: String apple="this is an apple";
    String orange="this is an orange";
    String banana="this is a banana";

Comment: lets suppose these are my strings in java file.and i want to navigate it one by one in an edit text throgh next button

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve something like the following image .

add `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` in your `EditText` (in `layout.xml`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to highlight the words one after another, you can do something like this:

```
public int index = 0; //word that is highlighted at this moment

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
EditText editTextView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and then in the onClick method:

```
String textInEditText = editTextView.getText().toString();
String[] words = textInEditText.split(' ');
String toBeHighlighted = words[index];
toBeHighlighted = "<font color='red'>"+toBeHighlighted+"</font>");
textInEditText.replace(words[index], toBeHighlighted);
editTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textInEditText));
index++; // move to next word
```

Comment: String apple="this is an apple";
    String orange="this is an orange";
    String banana="this is a banana";                                                                  
lets suppose these are my strings in java file.and i want to navigate it one by one in an edit text throgh next button

Comment: then you can do the same, that I wrote, but instead of String[] words = textInEditText.split(' '); you will have an array of your statements and everything else is the same